# New outer automorphism for $G_1 \times G_2$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, lie-groups, group-homomorphism, automorphism-group

Suppose $G_1$ is a group, which has no outer automorphism.

Suppose $G_2$ is a group, which has no outer automorphism.

> Main Question: What are the possible conditions to know can there be an outer automorphism for 
>   $$
> G_1 \times G_2?
> $$

An easier question:

Suppose $G_1=SU(2)$ is a group, which has no outer automorphism.

Suppose $G_2= \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ is a group, which has no outer automorphism.

- $SU(2) \times SU(2)$ has however a order-2 outer automorphism.
- $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ has however a order-2 outer automorphism.

> Simpler Question: Is there an  outer automorphism for
>   $$
> SU(2) \times \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} ?
> $$

If you can answer anything of the above two Questions - this counts as a perfect answer.

Answer (score 4):

A sufficient condition is that $G_1$ has a central subgroup $C$ isomorphic to a quotient of $G_2$ - this holds for your example.

We then have a natural map $q:G_2\to C$.

> The map $\phi:G_1\times G_2\to G_1\times G_2:(g,h)\mapsto (gq(h),h)$ is an outer automorphism.

Comment: How do we show this? thanks +1!!

Comment: just check the definition of automorphism. Injective: $\phi(g,h)=(1,1)$ then immediately $h=1$ so $q(1)=1$ gives $g=1$. Surjective: $(g,h)=\phi(gq(h)^{-1},h)$. Homomorphism: A little long for a comment, but straightforward

Comment: Should it be intead a natural map $q:G_2\to C$. The map $\phi:G_1\times G_2\to G_1\times G_2:(g,h)\mapsto (gq(h),h)$ is an outer automorphism???

Comment: yep, typo, well spotted